# What’s the most secure way to obtain & use a computer

Tags: network

What’s the most secure way to obtain (purchase) & then use a computer/device?

I.e. even if I pay cash for a Mac at Apple. Right when I put in my Ethernet cable wouldn’t Apple see my IP address and be able to link that to a person?

Comment: It sounds like your question is more "What's the most anonymous way to obtain and use a computer", the thing you are concerned about being seemingly having the user identity revealed...

Comment: Your ISP already knows your name and location and they're the ones assigning the IP address. No privacy options are going to change that. Apple is not going to be involved unless you contact them. Turning off updates might help privacy but then you shouldn't be on the internet.

Comment: As with all things security, you need to answer "secure against ***what***?"

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider buying a computer, wiping the hard drive clean, then installing an open source operating system that does not 'call home' (at least, not without asking your permission first).  After wiping the drive clean, install the OS on the system from scratch, using an ISO from a distributor that you trust. And, proceed with the installation only after you have verified the distributor's signature on the ISO.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a bitcoin cleaning service and a degree in computer science.

1. Clean some BTC
2. Use it at an online retailer which accepts BTC for a raspberry pi
3. Have it mailed to a secure mail forwarding service
4. Read up on the Yocto project
5. Build a custom Yocto distribution which contains only thoroughly
   vetted software and never connects to any server if not through a VPN (Anonymously paid for in BTC, of course)
6. Only use it with public wifi

A high powered yagi may help on the last point if you don't live close to a public shopping center